# Combine multiple fractions into one using SymPy (Python)

Tags: python, julia, sympy

I have a **symbolic** expression (say, `var_1`) with is a sum of around ten fractions, each being a complex combination of many parameters. `var_1` arises after performing several operations into other expressions. In other words, `var_1` is an **output** and not an input. This is, **I only have `var_1` and not its individual components**.

By construction, I know that when `var_1` is written as one fraction (using the least common multiple as denominator), then the nominator is zero. I am confirming this with the SymPy library of Python (I am actually using SymPy in Julia but operations are the same).

I am looking for a function that combines multiple fractions into one, but applied to a single variable like `var_1`. `factor(var_1)` doesn't work. It seems SymPy stops factoring due to the complexity of the expression `var_1`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there are many standard functions that add up fractions in SymPy. For example, `simplify`, `fraction`, `ratsimp`, etc. See the **developers** section for a complete list of functions ([link here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/simplify/simplify.html)).

The problem in my case is that the expression I have is too complex to be handled by those functions. Therefore the above functions return as output the same input. Yet, my problem was solved by the function `powsimp` **with the option** `force=true`. This is, I called `powsimp(var_1,force=true)` in Julia (I think it is `powsimp(var_1,force=True)` in Python). I am not sure myself why that option works but it does!